# En My SQL workbench ¿Como represento una relacion reflexiva, y una relacion jerarquica?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Estoy haciendo un proyecto final de grado, y necesito hacer un modelo relacional en My SQL workbench, tengo varias jerarquias, y una relacion reflexiva, y en las herramientas que me proporciona no puedo hacer la jerarquia, ¿Alguna ayudita?.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Workbench no es más que una herramienta para administrar la DB. Supongo que cuando dices que no te proporciona la herramienta es porque estás utilizando algún editor visual, pero puedes saltarte eso y escribir directamente el DML para realizar lo que quieres y enviarlo directamente al motor.

Answer (score 0):

La relación jerárquica no deja de ser un caso particular de una relación reflexiva, cuyo modelo ER puedes representar así:

[image: Modelo ER de una relación jerárquica]

Y ya el diagrama de su implementación una base de datos real, como el que podría facilitarte el Workbench, podría ser así:

[image: Diagrama de una relación reflexiva]